# Need help Updating data from two database and two tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to update data from another table/databases

Database 1 = Client, Table 1 = Customer$

Account Number, Zip and Phone

Database 2 = Site10  and Insurance

Need to update Site 10 with Zip from Database 1 which is the client

Need Help????

Comment: What have you tried, and what is the table structure: especially, what data is used to correlate the data from DB1 and DB2?

Comment: Are both databases on the same DB server?

Comment: are you trying to do this from your db's client directly or are you using a language, (cause normally for something like this, I would just whip up a quick script in either ruby or perl).  Also are both DBs the same vendor (IE both mysql?)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the key fields to link the two tables together, so, assuming these databases both reside on the same server, and assuming that "AccountNumber" in the "Customer$" table in Database 1 is the key to the Site10 table in Database2:

```
UPDATE Database2.Site10 
SET Zip=Database1.Customer$.Zip
INNER JOIN Database1.Customer$
ON Database1.Customer$.AccountNumber = Database2.Site10.AccountNumber
```

If "INNER" is not valid on your particular database, this should also work:

```
UPDATE Database2.Site10 
SET Zip=Database1.Customer$.Zip
FROM Database2.Site10, Database1.Customer$
WHERE Database2.Site10.AccountNumber =  Database1.Customer$.AccountNumber
```

Comment: Both Databases reside on SQL2008 or Enterprise MGR...same server just different databases

Comment: tried the query above and received error message of 
Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Inner'. 

I have checked and everything looks good.

Comment: Inner might not be valid on your particular database--it is valid on SQL Server.

Try replacing everything from the "INNER" to the end of the code with this instead:
FROM Database2.Site10, Database1.Customer$
WHERE Database2.Site10.AccountNumber = Database1.Customer$.AccountNumber